# How to check that a type is 'formattable' using type traits / concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

I would like to check if a certain type can be used with `std::format`.

This is my naive attempt:

```
template<typename Object>
concept formattable = requires(const Object & obj)
{
    std::format("{}", obj);
};
```

But this does not work. It basically returns true for all types. Even those that can't be used with std::format.

`static_assert(!formattable<std::vector<int>>); // should return false`

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update:

With the introduction of [Formatting Ranges](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2286r8.html), there is already a concept in C++23 dedicated to testing whether a type is formattable, namely [`std::formattable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formattable).

---

Since `std::format` is not a constrained function, the expression `std::format("{}", obj)` is always well-formed. You might want to do

```
#include <format>
    
template<typename T>
concept formattable = requires (T& v, std::format_context ctx) {
  std::formatter<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>().format(v, ctx);
};
```

which mainly based on the constraints of the `basic_format_arg`'s constructor in [[format.arg]](https://eel.is/c++draft/format.arg#4).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s9Esj4rhs)

Comment: Can you explain why the line `std::format_context::template` is necessary? I'm not that familiar with the syntax.

Comment: @EladMaimoni Access the template type alias defined in [`std::format_context`](https://eel.is/c++draft/format.context).

Comment: @elad The `template` keyword informs the compiler that the immediately following `formatter_type < std::remove_cvref_t` is part of a template for all T's, and not sometimes a comparison. C++ has a crazy syntax!

Comment: I don't think `template` is necessary here, since `std::format_context` is not a dependent name.